Stagger data going into FIFO in a pipelined system
In a pipelined system, 32 bits of data is generated. The upper and lower 16 bits represent different data words. The whole 32 bits are written into a FIFO. The system that reads from the FIFO shall process the lower 16 bits and then the upper 16 bits.

This means that once the FIFO is popped, the lower 16 bits are processed, then the upper 16 bits are processed and then the FIFO is popped again. However, the module writing into the FIFO writes 32 bits into it at a time.
My question is, is there a way to stagger the data going into the FIFO such that I write the lower 16 bits of the 32 bit and then the upper 16 bits? I have decided that to keep the system simpler, it is better to the let the downstream module deal with the problem by using an FSM while the upstream module is fully pipelined and writes 32 bits at a time.
The question is theoretical. Is it possible for the fully pipelined module writing into FIFO to some how write the 32 bits word as two 16 bit chunks i.e lower 16 bits followed by upper 16 bits?

AND 0xFFFF and AND 0xFFFF0000 with right shift by 16 (two commands for most micros) seems pretty simple to me.

This is about digital design. The design has been created in RTL using VHDL. The module is pipelined which means that it is supposed to generate a new output every cycle as long as the input keeps coming in.

Mux at the beginning or mux at the end.  Same difference, but one does not waste half a fifo.

I'm not sure I understand the question, but sure, it's certainly possible to clock two 16-bit words into the FIFO for every 32-bit word that comes out of the source module — you just need to clock the FIFO twice as fast as the module.
Obviously, the system at the output of the FIFO needs to be able to process 16-bit words at that rate, at least on average; otherwise, it becomes the bottleneck in the pipeline, limiting the overall throughput.
Would it be better to have two copies of the system at the output so that the two 16-bit words coming out of the FIFO could be processed in parallel?

Usual implementations of FIFO only account for whole addresses. So if you have a 32-bit word line, doing a 16-bit write would move the write pointer to the next address.
If the addressing was made for 16-bit words, then it would be optimal for your proposal.
